# How to reset selected radio buttons when closing slideToggle?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, reset, slidetoggle

I have a simple slideToggle setup that opens a div on a page. Some of the divs have a self test in them. I'm having trouble figuring out how to reset the radio buttons when the div is closed. Here is the jQuery:

```
$("h2.titleTrigger").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

//TOGGLE OPEN/CLOSE THE DIV
$(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
return false;
});


//self test

$('input:radio').bind('change',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var parentId = $(this).parents('.selfTest').attr('id');
$('#'+parentId+' .selfTestWrong').addClass('answerShown');
$('#'+parentId+' .selfTestAnswer').slideDown(300);
});
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/3XBgu/

What is the best way to reset the self test to it's un-selected state when the user closes the slideToggle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$("h2.titleTrigger").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //TOGGLE OPEN/CLOSE THE DIV
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");

    // Re-set all the radio buttons
    $('input:radio').prop('checked', false);

    // Re-set all the labels class
    $('.selfTestWrong').removeClass('answerShown');
    return false;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3XBgu/1/)

Comment: This works perfectly! I also added $('.selfTestAnswer').slideUp(300); to re-hide the answer paragraph. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem:

```
//TOGGLE OPEN/CLOSE THE DIV
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
    $(".hey").each(function(){
        this.checked = false; 
        $('.selfTestWrong').removeClass('answerShown');
        $('.selfTestAnswer').hide();
    });
return false;
});
```

(Added class="hey" to each input)

http://jsfiddle.net/3XBgu/2/