# Reset radio buttons only if the div they're in is toggled closed, but not if another div is toggled open?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, slidetoggle

I have a page with multiple jQuery slideToggles. Earlier, I asked a question about how to reset selections in one of the toggles when the toggle is closed here: [How to reset selected radio buttons when closing slideToggle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220747/how-to-reset-selected-radio-buttons-when-closing-slidetoggle)

The problem now is that if I toggle open the next one on the page, it resets the self test in the other open toggle.  I want to ensure that the test resets only if the div containing the self test is toggled closed, not when the next one is toggled open.

Is there a way to say "reset the self test only if the div it's in is toggled closed, but not if another div is toggled open"?

jQuery:
    $("h2.titleTrigger").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

```
//TOGGLE OPEN/CLOSE THE DRAWER
$(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");

//UNDO THE SELF TEST
$('.selfTestWrong').removeClass('answerShown');
$('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
$('.selfTestAnswer').slideUp(300);

return false;
});

//self test

$('input:radio').bind('change',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var parentId = $(this).parents('.selfTest').attr('id');
$('#'+parentId+' .selfTestWrong').addClass('answerShown');
$('#'+parentId+' .selfTestAnswer').slideDown(300);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bY7jp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes:

```
//TOGGLE OPEN/CLOSE THE DRAWER
$(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
$(this).next().children(".selfTest").children(".selfTestWrong").removeClass("answerShown");
$(this).next().children(".selfTest").children("input:radio").prop("checked", false);
$(this).next().children(".selfTest").children(".selfTestAnswer").slideUp(300);
```

This finds the closest inputs in the selected div. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bY7jp/3/

Comment: Love that! Works great on jsFiddle, but on my site, the answer paragraph (.selfTestAnswer) slides up, but the radio box stays checked and the .answerShown class does not remove. Suggestions?

Comment: Hmm...are you sure the class names are what they should be? There may also be an issue with the HTML markup on your site vs. the fiddle. The selectors are based off specific children, if the HTML markup doesn't match, the script won't perform.